# ng-model not bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get jsondata from controller and use ng-repeat to fill table

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in customerlist">
    <td>{{customer.fistname}}</td>
    <td>{{customer.lastame}}</td>
    <td id="emailid" >{{customer.email}}</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="customeropt" id="customeropt" ng-click="editCustomer(customer.email)" >Edit</a></td>
</tr>
```

After I get data from the table and I want to set data to input for editing
I get data by using editCustomer(customer.email)

```
$scope.editCustomer = function(email){
   var edit = this;    
   $scope.emailid = email;
   console.log(email);
    return email;
}
```

How set data to an input field or another html tag.
When I use ng-model and ng-change for any HTML tag it's not update when I click on "Edit"

```
<h2 ng-model="changedData" ng-change="changeData()">Email: {{changedData}}</h2>
    <input ng-model="changedData" ng-change="changeData()">
```

The ng-change function:

```
$scope.changeData = function(){
       $scope.changedData;
   console.log($scope.changedData);
}
```

And sorry for my English is not my native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

html:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="customer in customerlist">
    <td>{{customer.fistname}}</td>
    <td>{{customer.lastame}}</td>
    <td id="emailid" >{{customer.email}}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="customeropt" id="customeropt" 
            data-ng-click="editCustomer(customer)" >Edit</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<h2>Email: {{ customer.email }}</h2>
<input data-ng-model="customer.email">
```

js:

```
$scope.customer =
    {
        firstname: "",
        lastname: "",
        email: ""
    }
$scope.editCustomer = function(customer){
    $scope.customer.firstname = customer.firstname;
    $scope.customer.lastname = customer.lastname;
    $scope.customer.email = customer.email;
}
```

Let me know how it goes.

**Edit**

Here's why it works: The [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive on  creates a `customer` object for each row . The [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) event on  passes the `customer` object for that row . Inside the event handler, `editCustomer`, a [scope variable](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) name `$scope.customer` is assigned the properties of the `customer`. The  has a two-way binding with $scope.customer using the [ng-model directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) so that the scope variable is changed whenever the  value changes.

Comment: @Jmax - See edited answer. If you don't mind, since it's the right answer, upvoting me.